# How to transform categorical values of a dataframe column to a one-hot encoded columns in sckikit-learn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

Given the column `letters` with categorical values `['A', 'B','C']` of the dataframe `df`, I want to obtain many columns in the dataframe, where each row has just one non-zero value corresponding to the original categorical value.

For example from the dataframe

```
letters
A
C
A
C
```

I want to have:

```
A    B    C
1    0    0
0    0    1 
1    0    0
0    0    1
```

Now in pandas this is very easy:

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.letters)
res = pd.concat([df, dummies], axis=1)
df.drop('letters', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

In scikit the `LabelBinarizer` can be used:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
cat_col = df["letters"]
encoder = LabelBinarizer()
col_1hot = encoder.fit_transform(cat_col)
col_1hot.toarray()
```

However this is just a `1-0` matrix and I've lost the references to the original categorical value. Thus, I cannot assume the first 1-hot column is `A`, the second is `B` and so on. 
So how do I execute one-hot encoding in SciKit learn to obtain a dataframe?

**EDIT**

@Joe Halliwell suggested doing something `lb.inverse_transform(onehot)` so in this specific case I did

```
lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
onehot = lb.fit_transform(df)
res = pd.DataFrame(data=onehot, columns=lb.inverse_transform(onehot).reshape(-1,))
```

which works in this case because the number of rows is equal to the categories. If I have more rows, this does not work anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use SciKit Learn to obtain a DataFrame. You can however call the `inverse_transform` method on your fitted `LabelBinarizer` to retrieve the labels e.g.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing

df = pd.DataFrame({"foo": ["A", "C", "B", "A"]})
lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
onehot = lb.fit_transform(df)
print(lb.inverse_transform(onehot))
```

So, in order to retrieve the labels for the columns in your one-hot encoded matrix, you can run the identity matrix through the inverse transform:

```
print(lb.inverse_transform(np.identity(onehot.shape[1]))
```

Comment: `lb.inverse_transform(encoder)` might be useful when the number of rows equals the number of categories but otherwise it does not help: see edit of my question

Comment: I've added a note on how to retrieve all the labels in the correct order.